# How to disable click jquery when got class 'active'

Tags: jquery, sizzle

I want to disable clicking when `div.button ol.control li` has class `active`.
I already use `.bind()`, but it's not working, please, help me, thanks!

this my script http://jsfiddle.net/surya31/HcaBS/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to disable, you can explicitly negate it in the selector:

```
$('div.button ol.control li:not(.active)').click(function(){ ...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('your-selector').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('active'))
        return false;
});
```